# How to inherit from base controller using "controller as" syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is a snippet demonstrating how to inherit from a base controller using `$controller` and `$scope`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('BaseCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope
  })
});

app.controller('BaseCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I do the same using "controller as" syntax? This snippet demonstrates what I am after, but it doesn't work:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('BaseCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope
  })
});

app.controller('BaseCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p>Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use controller as syntax (or just use the ctrl instance returned by `$controller` provider) and use `angular.extend`. But i don't think there is another way implicitly angular would do this, since "controller as" syntax ultimately places the controller instance on the respective scope as a property name specified as alias. But this really isn't inheritance, but utilizing object extension.

```
var ctrl = $controller('BaseCtrl as base', { //You don't really need to use as syntax here though
   $scope: $scope
});

angular.extend(this, ctrl);
```

---

```
//or

$controller('BaseCtrl as base', { //You don't really need to use as syntax here though
   $scope: $scope
});
angular.extend(this, $scope.base); //With as syntax
```

---

Or you could use [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) at the implementation level of the controller constructors itself. There are lots of syntactic sugars available, typescript's [`extends`](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/extending-classes-and-interfaces-using-typescript#content) there is another nice and simple [example here](https://www.exratione.com/2013/10/two-approaches-to-angularjs-controller-inheritance/) as well.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
 var ctrl = $controller('BaseCtrl as base', {
    $scope: $scope
  });
 
  angular.extend(this, ctrl);
});

app.controller('BaseCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p>Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great! In your snippet example, what if there is an async function call in the base controller constructor? How would angular.extend work in that case, if not all the properties are populated by the time it runs? I didn't see any async callback for $controller, which is unfortunate.

Comment: That is a good question. In such case which could be pretty common, you could make use of object reference from the base controller http://plnkr.co/edit/4ug9kd9qgEtAW3XuXdxy?p=preview or with the alias property of base on the derived controller http://plnkr.co/edit/C82OBW?p=preview `$controller` is really designed to use with scope inheritance, but i guess controller as syntax mostly for its usability in the view without worriyng much about the dot syntax, child scope issues etc. So any controller level prototypical inheritance we would need to implement on our own, atleast as of now.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the examples and explanations. I'd been chasing my tail on this one for a while... I agree that prototypical inheritance is probably the better way to go but I figured there was a way to do it with `$controller` as well.

Comment: Your level: Genious! Thank you