# AngularJS Controller Inheritance: "this" not pointing to the child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I am using the controllerAs syntax.

I used $controller to inherit from a parent (more like a base or abstract) controller. I found this [*question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351163/how-to-inherit-from-base-controller-using-controller-as-syntax) not long ago which I based on.

I noticed that when I use a function which uses a controller property (`this.propName`), it does not use the current controller `this`, but the parent's. Here's a [demo (plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/lY8qKm2Xg56A6oCCtHsv?p=preview).

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/srph/60df7c5ec6139fbe0d6f) to both my *parent controller* and *child* controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update sayMyName method to following:

```
function sayMyName() {
  alert(this.me);
}
```

As you are trying to pick `me` property on the base controller the alert should pick `me` value from the corresponding instance and not the instance when it was created which is `vm`

Updated plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqzXGzNqiqMPk1nAiB16?p=preview)

Comment: Good catch, `me` is a local variable stored in closure.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('BaseController',function() {
    this.me = 'Base';
    this.sayMe= function() {
        alert(this.me);
    }
});
app.controller('ChildController', function($scope, $controller) {
    var controller = $controller('BaseController as base', {$scope: $scope});
    angular.extend(this, controller);
    this.me = 'Child';
});
```